# android : How can I compress a bitmap in download

Tags: java, android, bitmap

my application downloads a bitmap :

```
public byte[] getUrlImgContent(String urlstring) throws IOException
{
    byte[] imageRaw = null;
    URL url = new URL(urlstring);

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    urlConnection.connect();
    if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                    urlConnection.getInputStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int c;
            while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                out.write(c);
            }
            out.flush();

            imageRaw = out.toByteArray();

            urlConnection.disconnect();
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageRaw;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and i'm directly converting it to bitmap and showing it in a zoomable-imageview

the problem : the application crashes if the file size is too big

what should I do to reduce the image's size ? (format : jpg)

Comment: where is it crashing?

Comment: on loading the 8th page (other page are deleted from memory before setting the new image)

Comment: and I know the problem by checking the logcat.
my problem is reducing image size.

Comment: u have already posted same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647403/android-application-crashes-while-loading-many-images 
few mins back...try bitmapoptions, sample size

Comment: check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object?rq=1
answer by Fedor