# Out of memory error when using Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase

I implement firebase google (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2), but when I call

```
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

I get a message Out of memory.  I'm a beginner android, I don't know the reason. How I can fix this problem?
Here is the log:

```
>1.424 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 162 byte allocation with 12 free bytes and 12B until OOM" (recursive case)
06-10 02:03:51.454 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art: "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
06-10 02:03:51.454 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x7493a000 self=0xb4827800
06-10 02:03:51.454 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art:   | sysTid=4944 nice=-11 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f35bec
06-10 02:03:51.454 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=898 stm=49 core=1 HZ=100
06-10 02:03:51.454 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art:   | stack=0xbe7e8000-0xbe7ea000 stackSize=8MB
06-10 02:03:51.454 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
06-10 02:03:51.454 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art:   native: #00 pc 00004e64  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
06-10 02:03:51.454 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art:   native: #01 pc 00003665  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
06-10 02:03:51.454 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art:   native: #02 pc 00244159  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+68)
06-10 02:03:51.454 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art:   native: #03 pc 00227059  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+140)
06-10 02:03:51.454 4944-4944/com.bsp.androidtraining E/art:   native: #04 pc 0022a31b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(char const*)+254)

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack available
```

Comment: Is this happening on the real device? Try clearing the cache and see if this helps. Alternatively, you can add `android:largeHeap="true"` in your `Manifest.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks! I work for me.

Comment: Glad this helped. Actually I should have suggested this as an answer - please review my answer and accept it so that your question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Out of Memory errors usually disappear if you set `android:largeHeap="true"` in the Manifest.xml file - but in most cases, care should be taken to ensure you are not unnecessarily loading large amounts of data in memory. For example, look at the discussion in this closely related article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359024/out-of-memory-error-while-loading-bitmaps).

However, in your case I think you can just set `android:largeHeap="true"` in the `Manifest.xml` file. This should help.