# java.lang.outofmemoryerror: failed to allocate a 15451212 byte allocation with 11809808 free bytes and 11mb until oom

Tags: android

I am new to this android world..so please help...
I am writing my own custom adapter using the GridView to populate images..but every time the above error is crashing my app..enclosing my MainActivity File, COdeAdapterFile

**This is MainActivityCode**
 com.example.android.internship;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Handicrafts extends AppCompatActivity  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
//THIS IS ARTIFACTS FILE
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    NavigationView nv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_handicrafts);

        nv=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.mynavigation);
        nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mToolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final ArrayList<Items> itemObject = new ArrayList<Items>();

        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a1));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a2));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a3));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a4));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a5));

        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a6));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a7));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a8));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a9));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a10));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a11));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a12));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a13));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a14));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a15));

        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a16));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a17));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a18));
        itemObject.add(new Items("",R.drawable.a19));


        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, itemObject);

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach the adapter to the listView.
        GridView newGrdidView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        newGrdidView.setAdapter(adapter);
        final int []images={R.drawable.a1,R.drawable.a2,R.drawable.a3,R.drawable.a4,R.drawable.a5,R.drawable.a6,R.drawable.a7,R.drawable.a8,
                R.drawable.a9,R.drawable.a10,R.drawable.a11,R.drawable.a12,R.drawable.a13,R.drawable.a14,R.drawable.a15,R.drawable.a16,R.drawable.a17,
                R.drawable.a18,R.drawable.a19,};

        newGrdidView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Handicrafts.this,
                        Main3Activity.class);
                int mImageId =0;
                intent.putExtra("img",images[position]);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {return true;}
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.paint:
                Intent paintIntent=new Intent(Handicrafts.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(paintIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.covers:
                Intent collageIntent=new Intent(Handicrafts.this,collages.class);
                startActivity(collageIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.artifacts:
                Intent craftsIntent=new Intent(Handicrafts.this,Handicrafts.class);
                startActivity(craftsIntent);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**This is customAdapter code**

```
package com.example.android.internship;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.R.attr.id;
import static android.R.attr.resource;

/**
 * Created by hatim on 6/6/2017.
 */

public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {
    public ItemAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<Items> itemObject) {
        super(context,0,itemObject);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View gridview=convertView;
        if(gridview==null)
        {
            gridview = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        }

        Items currentItems = getItem(position);

        TextView nameTextView = null;
        if (gridview != null) {
            nameTextView = (TextView) gridview.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        }
        // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the name TextView
        nameTextView.setText(currentItems.getItemName());

        ImageView iconView = null;
        if (gridview != null) {
            iconView = (ImageView) gridview.findViewById(R.id.product_images);

        }
        // Get the image resource ID from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set the image to iconView
        iconView.setImageResource(currentItems.getImageId());


        return gridview;
    }
}
```

**This my Android Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.internship">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Main3Activity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".collages"
            android:label="Cushion covers" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Handicrafts"
            android:label="Artefacts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**PLEASE HELP ME!!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Out of Memory Error while loading bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359024/out-of-memory-error-while-loading-bitmaps)

Comment: didn't get you will you please elaborate...with solution

Comment: can you post stack trace of exception from Android monitor

Comment: Probable duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200256/out-of-memory-error-imageview-issue). Try to recycle bitmap of your ImageView before you update your iconView's drawable. But first of all consider using view holder approach as a best practice for simple ListView and GridView controls

Comment: `15451212 byte allocation` -- this is equivalent to a 1965 x 1965 pixel image. This is **much too large**. If this is coming from your resources, either they are too large or are in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `RecyclerView` and `ViewHolder` approach and you can also use `Picasso` or `Glide` library to smooth loading of image into `ImageView`.
You are tying to show images in a grid manner, so I think you can use `RecyclerView` and make the `RecyclerView` `LayoutManager` in stack format.

```
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

Have a look at this - https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview
Let me know if any problem occur!

**your_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="and.com.bakingtime.activity.MainActivity">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**your_adapter_class.java**

```
public class your_adapter_class extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

    private List<ItemObject> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(context).load((itemList.get(position).getPhoto()).into(holder.thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }
}
```

**your_ViewHolder.java**

```
public class your_ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView thumbnail;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        thumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**
In your `MainActivity onCreate` making a `GridLayoutManager` and attaching it to your `recyclerView`

```
      private GridLayoutManager lLayout;

      // inside onCreate
       List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
        lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2);

        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

        RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, rowListItem);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

    //getAllItemList method
    private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){

    List<ItemObject> itemObject = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();

    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a1));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a2));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a3));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a4));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a5));

    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a6));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a7));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a8));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a9));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a10));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a11));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a12));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a13));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a14));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a15));

    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a16));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a17));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a18));
    itemObject.add(new ItemObject("",R.drawable.a19));

    return ItemObject;
}
```